# Specifying Application Root when Deploying to Azure from Github

Tags: azure, web-deployment

I'm using the new Window Azure Portal to deploy a php application from Github, but I can't find a way to set the application root to my public_html folder.

There's obviously private files in my repo which I don't want to be publicly accessible once deployed.

I've been Googling for an hour but the documentation for realistic scenarios like this is extremely poor.

I see an 'app settings' section, is this just for defining environment variables? I've also tried setting DocumentRoot in a .htaccess file in the root of the repo, but no luck.

Overall really impressed by Azure, but this is a deal breaker for me! Cheers.

Comment: Fixed by adding a .deployment file to the root with the following contents:


    [config]
    project = public_html


Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-us/f3dbfb9e-b70f-4409-a118-cc3ebdf985b7/git-deploy-subdirectory

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer possibly with more details.

Comment: It seems to me this only works when deploying from Git. Can somebody confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

As you found, [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments) explains how you can do this using a .deployment file.

Note that you can also do this by setting an equivalent App Setting in the Azure portal (i.e. Project=public_html) in case you prefer not to modify your repo.